# Deleting rows in labelframes in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to be able to delete a row from a labelframe but not sure how to do this.

I have a labelframe which you can add a row by clicking a button. But I'm not sure how to delete a row.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Umm, the [labelframe](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/labelframe.htm)s I know of don't have buttons.

Comment: You need to show us the code where you are adding rows into the labelframe.  It is impossible to answer your question without know what you are doing.